# How to show that $\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)^y = \left( 1 + \frac 1{y-1}\right)^y $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to show

> \[\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)^y = \left( 1 + \frac 1{y-1}\right)^y \]

I cannot understand how they made this step! Can someone explain how this works?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have
\[
\frac y{y-1} = \frac{y-1+1}{y-1} = \frac{y-1}{y-1} + \frac 1{y-1} = 1 + \frac 1{y-1}. \]

Comment: Thank you very much Martini! Perfect!

Answer (score 6):

$$
\frac{y}{y-1} = \frac{y-1+1}{y-1} = \frac{y-1}{y-1} + \frac{1}{y-1} = 1+ \frac{1}{y-1}
$$

There's the line of thought I use. You add and subtract one (adds up to zero, so it's allowed), then you rearrange everything to get the final result.

Edit: crud, not quick enough...

Comment: Thank you very much, i had totally forgotten about that "method". But now it is clear!

Comment: This is the same @martini did (+1). :)